# How to a pull a window to my second monitor that's above the current one when the menu bar is in the way?

Tags: display, window-manager

The menu bar is in the way so I can't pull one of my windows there. I had to move the bar up to that monitor as well so it wouldn't be in the way.

Comment: Are you talking about the menu bar at the top of the screen?

Comment: @bneely Yes I am.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this in Snow Leopard (10.6.8) without issues...

Menu bar on bottom (primary) screen, secondary screen above and dragging windows between the two is no problem.

To do this, I've used the following configuration under **Displays** in **System Preferences**:

[image: Dual display setup]

Check that your settings match and let us know how you get on.

Comment: I'm using lion, sorry.

Comment: its the same configuration in Lion.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit tricky, I use [Moom](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12) and set a keyboard shortcut to move windows between screens which like win key + shift + (left or right) on windows.